# Why does the Fused Multiply Add CSA use the inverted MSB of the addend when one multiply operand is negative?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, alu, floating-point

I found one valuable [paper](http://eece.cu.edu.eg/%7Ehfahmy/thesis/2012_03_bfpfma.pdf) about the "Fused Multiply Add":

> Instead of using 161-bit CSA, **Only the 106 least-significant** bits of the
> aligned A are needed as input to the **3:2 CSA**, because the product (i.e. sum and
> carry vectors) has only 106 bits and The 55 most-significant bits will be **sign
> extension bits** which have two cases {0, 0} if both sum and carry vectors are
> positive or {0, 1} if one of them is negative. For the 55 most significant bits, we
> use two multiplexers, one to select between A and **inverted A** as a sum vector and
> the second one to select between zeros and A as a carry vector by **Xor-ing sign
> extension bits** then the outputs of the two multiplexers are concatenated at the
> output of the CSA to obtain the 161-bit sum and carry words, see Figure (3-8).

The Figure (3-8):

[image]

From my perspective, when `C` or `S` is negative, the sign bit of `C` or `S` will be extended, so using \$1111\ldots\$ may be more reasonable than the **inverted A**.

Q: why does the above diagram use inverted A instead of sign extension of the negative sign (i.e. \$1111\ldots\$)?